# I can't configure php on serwer nginx for BigBlueButton

Tags: nginx, php

Hi I have problem with configuration a nginx for php, because I have installed BigBlueButton and I would install php in /var/www/bigbluebutton-default. When I add this to bigbluebutton in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and i try in browser /index.php and I see "404 Not Found"
My configuration file:

```
server { listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
 server_name  ns342679.ip-91-121-133.eu;
root /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;     
access_log  /var/log/nginx/bigbluebutton.access.log;

 # Handle RTMPT (RTMP Tunneling).  Forwards requests
 # to Red5 on port 5080
  location ~ (/open/|/close/|/idle/|/send/|/fcs/) {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5080;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;

      proxy_buffering            off;
      keepalive_requests         1000000000;
  }

 # Handle desktop sharing tunneling.  Forwards
 # requests to Red5 on port 5080.
   location /deskshare {
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5080;
       proxy_redirect     default;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       client_max_body_size       10m;
       client_body_buffer_size    128k;
       proxy_connect_timeout      90;
       proxy_send_timeout         90;
       proxy_read_timeout         90;
       proxy_buffer_size          4k;
       proxy_buffers              4 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
       include    fastcgi_params;
   }
# BigBlueButton landing page.
    location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }
    location ~ .php$ {
    root /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include fastcgi_params; 
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/bigblubutton-default$fastcgi_script_name;

}
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
 access_log off;
 allow 127.0.0.1;
 allow 91.121.133.47;
 deny all;
 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
# Include specific rules for record and playback
    include /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/*.nginx;

    #error_page  404  /404.html;

    # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    }
}
```

Sorry for format, but I can't past this with full formating.

Answer (score 1):

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/bigblubutton-default$fastcgi_script_name;
```

You forgot a / in the path.